# Is it possible to analyze dex file directly with mobsf?

Tags: python, android, security, static-analysis, penetration-testing

I have several dex files that needs to be statically analyzed by [mobsf](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF) after unpacking the apk file because core code are inaccessible prior to unpacking.

What I've tried:
Adding Line 3 and changing line 4 from `glob_pattern = app_dir + *.dex'` to `glob_pattern = ddex_dir`

```
def get_dex_files(app_dir):
    """Get all Dex Files for analysis."""
    ddex_dir = "C:/path/Sample/dexfilepath/"
    glob_pattern = app_dir + '*.dex'
    return glob.glob(glob_pattern)
```

I know it's naïve approach but I'm really new into pentesting.

A portion of the error code:

```
[INFO] 08/Jan/2021 11:49:08 - Decompiling to Java with jadx
[INFO] 08/Jan/2021 11:49:30 - DEX -> SMALI
[INFO] 08/Jan/2021 11:49:30 - Converting 10046944_dexfile_execute.dex to Smali Code
[INFO] 08/Jan/2021 11:49:30 - Converting 10152568_dexfile_execute.dex to Smali Code
[INFO] 08/Jan/2021 11:49:30 - Converting 10247328_dexfile_execute.dex to Smali Code
[INFO] 08/Jan/2021 11:49:30 - Converting 10286360_dexfile_execute.dex to Smali Code
[INFO] 08/Jan/2021 11:49:30 - Converting 10453796_dexfile_execute.dex to Smali Code
[INFO] 08/Jan/2021 11:49:30 - Converting 1272952_dexfile_execute.dex to Smali Code
[INFO] 08/Jan/2021 11:49:30 - Converting 1349780_dexfile_execute.dex to Smali Code
[INFO] 08/Jan/2021 11:49:30 - Converting 13539468_dexfile_execute.dex to Smali Code
[INFO] 08/Jan/2021 11:49:30 - Converting 3046356_dexfile_execute.dex to Smali Code
[INFO] 08/Jan/2021 11:49:31 - Converting 3261832_dexfile.dex to Smali Code
[INFO] 08/Jan/2021 11:49:31 - Converting 3261832_dexfile_execute.dex to Smali Code
[INFO] 08/Jan/2021 11:49:31 - Converting 359592_dexfile_execute.dex to Smali Code
[INFO] 08/Jan/2021 11:49:31 - Converting 5068284_dexfile_execute.dex to Smali Code
[INFO] 08/Jan/2021 11:49:31 - Converting 8294920_dexfile.dex to Smali Code
Lcom/qinggan/ftp/library/ftp/QGFTPServer$MyFtplet;->onConnect(Lorg/apache/ftpserver/ftplet/FtpSession;)Lorg/apache/ftpserver/ftplet/FtpletResult;: Invalid debug offset
Lcom/qinggan/ftp/library/socket/message/QGP2PMessageBase;->obtainHead(I)Ljava/lang/String;: Invalid debug offset
Lcom/qinggan/ftp/library/socket/message/QGP2PMessageServer$1;->run()V: Invalid debug offset
Lcom/qinggan/ftp/library/socket/message/QGP2PMessageClient$1;->run()V: Invalid debug offset
Lcom/qinggan/keepalive/GuardService;->getServiceIntent()Landroid/content/Intent;: Invalid debug offset
Lcom/qinggan/ftp/library/socket/message/QGP2PMessageClient;->closeSelf()V: Invalid debug offset
[INFO] 08/Jan/2021 11:49:32 - Converting 8294920_dexfile_execute.dex to Smali CodeLcom/qinggan/app/arielapp/ArielApplication$16;->insert(Ljava/util/List;)V: Invalid debug offset
Lcom/qinggan/ftp/library/ftp/QGFTPClient$2;->run()V: Invalid debug offset
Lcom/qinggan/app/arielapp/ArielApplication$11;->clearUserCache()V: Invalid debug offset
Lcom/qinggan/ftp/library/socket/message/QGP2PMessageServer;->dispatchMessage(Lcom/qinggan/ftp/library/socket/message/QGP2PMessage;)V: Invalid debug offset

Lcom/hp/hpl/sparta/DefaultLog;->error(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)V: Invalid debug offset
Lcom/qinggan/app/arielapp/ArielApplication$17;->onConnectStatusChange(Z)V: Invalid debug offset
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to use [dex2jar](https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar) tool for this purpose. Convert your apk to jar and then analyze it with MobSF. MobSF should work with jar files since this is an archive. I am not sure if it will show the stable behavior, but it can be an option.

As far as I know MobSF also have this package within it's source code, so did you try to load this APK directly to MobSF without changing anything? I think it might work.

Also you can use JADX tool for manual source code analyzing. It should restore the source code from the DEX binaries.

Also observe [this](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF/issues/1037) issue. MobSF developer suggests to use enjarify instead of dex2jar (2nd answer) and sends the [link](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF/blob/master/MobSF/settings.py#L266) which explains how to do it.

Comment: Using JADX and manually decompiling was the way to go. And just to clarify, the apk was obfuscated and required manual decompile through dex in order to access the core code; hence, it wasn't possible to analyze all of the aspect in the apk purely by uploading the apk by it self.

Comment: So in the end you've decompiled it using JADX and were able to load it to MobSF?

Comment: Here's my workflow: .dex =dex2jar=> jar =jadx=> .java which can be then copied pasted into the JAVA_Source under mobsf generated directory.

I was able to produce functional .java source code via decompiling dexes to jar using a **modified** version of dex2jar then using JADX to read the jar decompiled with d2j.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more refined version of my workflow after digging: .dex =dex2jar=> .jar =jadx=> .java which can be then copied pasted into the JAVA_Source under mobsf generated directory.

I was able to produce functional .java source code via decompiling dexes to jar using a **modified** version of dex2jar then using JADX to read the jar decompiled with d2j.